# Volver a correr un código después de recibir un error

Tags: python, selenium

estoy realizando unas pruebas con Selenium y Python. Mi problema surge porque hay un momento en el que el internet se va y esto ocasiona que el programa se "rompa", y por ende el programa termine su ejecución. Mi duda surge en saber si existe una manera que cuando el programa termine su ejecución se pueda poner a correr de nuevo. Utilizo Spyder como mi IDE. Mi código esta de la siguiente manera:

```
def main():
  #Funciones

if __name__ == '__main__':
  u = main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar los bloques `try` y `except` su función radica en el manejo de errores y para tomar acciones sobre ellos.

```
#Ejemplo de división de un numero sin try-except
n = int(input("Ingresa el numerador")
d = int(input("Ingresa el denominador")
print(f"El resultado de la division es {n/d}")
```

En el ejemplo de arriba si el usuario ingresa un 0 en el denominador o ingresa un valor no numérico el programa terminara con un error interrumpiendo con la ejecucion, para manejar esto podemos usar un `try-except`

```
#Ejemplo de división de un numero sin try-except
try:
    n = int(input("Ingresa el numerador")
    d = int(input("Ingresa el denominador")
    print(f"El resultado de la division es {n/d}")
except:
    print("Los valores ingresados son incorrectos")
```

Para este ejemplo si algo dentro de la parte del `try` arroja un error el programa no terminara si no que pasara a la parte de `except`, y continuara con la ejecución.

Desconozco la estructura de tu código pero deberia quedar masomenos asi:

```
#un ciclo infinito para volver a ejecutar desde el inicio (o desde donde se desee)
while True:
    #codigo
    try:
        #parte donde sucede el error
        funcion()
    except:
        #un continue para volver al while
        continue
    #codigo
```

Comment: Sí, más o menos me doy una idea. Ya puse como se ve el código que tengo. Creo que sería algo parecido a lo que me comentas ¿verdad?.

Comment: asi como esta tu codigo seria poner el `while True` y el `try` antes de `u = main()` y el `except:` `continue` despues de eso, aunque no es recomendable usar el try para grandes segmentos de codigo, si no para determinadas lineas en las cuales el error no se pueda controlar, como en el mal ingreso de datos por parte del usuario, para conexiones a bases de datos, manejo de archivos, etc. para tu caso es mejor que lo pongas solo en la parte donde te arroja el error.